# Computing an explicit 2-cocycle

Tags: group-theory

$H^2(S_3, \mathbb{ℤ}) = \mathbb{ℤ}/2\mathbb{ℤ}$, so there is a unique non-split central extension of $S_3$ by $\mathbb{ℤ}$. How could I go about actually finding this extension (or a 2-cocycle for it)?

Comment: One way to compute that is the LHS spectral sequence for the quotient by the center of the group. You can trace the cocycle to see from where it comes. Alternatively, the group is dihedral, so there is a well known projective resolution that can be used to compute its cohomology explicitly.

Comment: Could you point me to that projective resolution?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it is given as an example in Cartan-Eilenberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the action of $\mathbf{Z}$ on $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$ given by $n\cdot m=(-1)^nm$. Form the corresponding semidirect product $G=(\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z})\rtimes_{\pm}\mathbf{Z}$.

This is the desired group. Its center is the infinite cyclic subgroup $\{0\}\rtimes(2\mathbf{Z})$, and the quotient $(\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z})\rtimes_{\pm}(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$ is isomorphic to $S_3$. This is a non-split extension, because $G$ has no element of order 2.

Comment: Fantastic! Can I ask how you thought of this?

Comment: Every group with a central infinite cyclic subgroup $G$ actually has a surjective homomorphism onto $\mathbf{Z}$, with finite kernel $K$. I looked how $K$ maps in your $S_3$ quotient: first it maps injectively (because the kernel of your quotient map is torsion-free). Then what's the image of $K$ in $S_3$? a normal subgroup $S_3$, $A_3$, or $1$. First, 1 is excluded because $G$ is not infinite cyclic, second $S_3$ is excluded because your extension is not a direct product. It remains $A_3$, so $K$ is cyclic of order 3 and hence $G$ is a semidirect product of the form $(Z/3Z)\rtimes Z$.